# How invalidate layout only at ona indexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection that has cells with buttons.

[Short Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yklg.png)
[Long Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kivVe.png)

By clicking on these buttons, the cell height increases. To do this, I call `collectionView.invalidateLayout()`, but I noticed that after this method, `cellForItemAt` is called 4 times, although I only need to overload one indent (from the bottom of the cell that is increasing).

Now the code looks like this:

```
func setAndReload(cellMode: EventCellMode, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    data[indexPath.item].mode = cellMode
    let offset = collectionView.contentOffset
    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ShortEventCollectionViewCell
    cell.set(mode: cellMode)

    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
            self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.collectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that all my cells are not overloaded? I heard that this can be done with the help of an `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext`, but I did not find an implementation.

Comment: I don't think you need `invalidateLayout` here. Try `reloadItems` instead.